# OpenCL program doesn't recognize drivers when compiled with MinGW but functions normally when built using Visual Studio

Tags: compilation, opencl, mingw-w64

I've been working on an OpenCL program that trial factors Mersenne numbers. It works as expected when I compile it using Microsoft Visual Studio. But although it also compiles with MinGW (64-bit) without errors, the program doesn't seem to work with the OpenCL driver.

After the initialization routine, the program should print information about the selected device. However, the program immediately terminates after startup and does not print any errors. I tried the same thing on several computers, and it only worked on one. Anyone have an idea what might be causing this issue?

Here is the full repository for reference: https://github.com/Bdot42/mfakto

And here is the makefile with my modifications:

```
# set x86_64 (64-bit) as default
BITS := x86_64
BITFLAG := -m64

# check whether to build 32-bit version
ifdef bitness
  ifeq ($(bitness), 32)
    BITS := x86
    BITFLAG := -m32
  endif
endif

# Check if static linking is requested
ifdef static
  ifeq ($(static), yes)
    STATIC := -static
  endif
endif

# some commands won't work on Windows
ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
  CP = copy
  RM = del /f
else
  CP = cp
  RM = rm -f
endif

# where is the OpenCL SDK installed?
AMD_APP_DIR = c:\ocl
AMD_APP_INCLUDE = -I$(AMD_APP_DIR)\include
AMD_APP_LIB = -L$(AMD_APP_DIR)\lib\$(BITS)

# Change needed for compilation with amdgpu-pro
# AMD_APP_DIR = /opt/amdgpu-pro/opencl

# optimize or debug
#OPTIMIZE_FLAG = -O3
#OPTIMIZE_FLAG = -O3 -funroll-loops  -finline-functions -frerun-loop-opt -fgcse-sm -fgcse-las
OPTIMIZE_FLAG = -O3 -funroll-loops  -ffast-math -finline-functions -frerun-loop-opt -fgcse-sm -fgcse-las -flto
#OPTIMIZE_FLAG = -g

# Compiler settings for .c files (CPU)
CC = gcc
CPP = $(CC)
CFLAGS = $(BITFLAG) -Wall $(OPTIMIZE_FLAG) $(AMD_APP_INCLUDE) -DBUILD_OPENCL
CPP_FLAGS =
#CFLAGS_EXTRA_SIEVE = -funroll-all-loops
#CFLAGS_EXTRA_SIEVE = -funroll-all-loops -funsafe-loop-optimizations -fira-region=all -fsched-spec-load -fsched-stalled-insns=10 -fsched-stalled-insns-dep=10 -floop-parallelize-all -fvariable-expansion-in-unroller -fno-align-labels
CFLAGS_EXTRA_SIEVE = -funroll-all-loops -funsafe-loop-optimizations -fira-region=all -fsched-spec-load -fsched-stalled-insns=10 -fsched-stalled-insns-dep=10 -fno-align-labels


# Linker
LD = g++
LDFLAGS = $(BITFLAG) $(STATIC) $(OPTIMIZE_FLAG) $(AMD_APP_LIB) -lOpenCL

##############################################################################

CSRC  = sieve.c timer.c parse.c read_config.c mfaktc.c checkpoint.c \
    signal_handler.c filelocking.c output.c

# CLSRC = barrett15.cl  barrett.cl  common.cl  gpusieve.cl  mfakto_Kernels.cl  montgomery.cl  mul24.cl

COBJS  = $(CSRC:.c=.o) mfakto.o gpusieve.o perftest.o menu.o kbhit.o

##############################################################################

all: ../mfakto ../barrett15.cl  ../barrett.cl  ../common.cl  ../gpusieve.cl  ../mfakto_Kernels.cl  ../montgomery.cl  ../mul24.cl ../datatypes.h ../tf_debug.h ../mfakto.ini

../mfakto : $(COBJS)
    $(LD) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

clean :
    $(RM) *.o *~

sieve.o : sieve.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_EXTRA_SIEVE) -c $< -o $@

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $(CPP_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@

../%.cl : %.cl
    $(CP) $< ..

../%.h : %.h
    $(CP) $< ..

../%.ini : %.ini
    $(CP) $< ..

##############################################################################

# dependencies generated by cpp -MM (manually replaced AMD_APP_DIR)
#

checkpoint.o: checkpoint.c params.h timer.h

filelocking.o: filelocking.c

mfaktc.o: mfaktc.c $(AMD_APP_DIR)/include/CL/cl.h \
 $(AMD_APP_DIR)/include/CL/cl_platform.h params.h my_types.h compatibility.h \
 sieve.h read_config.h parse.h timer.h checkpoint.h signal_handler.h \
 filelocking.h perftest.h mfakto.h gpusieve.h output.h selftest-data.h

output.o: output.c params.h my_types.h $(AMD_APP_DIR)/include/CL/cl.h \
 $(AMD_APP_DIR)/include/CL/cl_platform.h output.h filelocking.h \
 compatibility.h

parse.o: parse.c compatibility.h filelocking.h parse.h

read_config.o: read_config.c params.h my_types.h \
 $(AMD_APP_DIR)/include/CL/cl.h $(AMD_APP_DIR)/include/CL/cl_platform.h

sieve.o: sieve.c params.h compatibility.h

signal_handler.o: signal_handler.c params.h my_types.h \
 $(AMD_APP_DIR)/include/CL/cl.h $(AMD_APP_DIR)/include/CL/cl_platform.h \
 compatibility.h

timer.o: timer.c timer.h compatibility.h

gpusieve.o: gpusieve.cpp $(AMD_APP_DIR)/include/CL/cl.h \
 $(AMD_APP_DIR)/include/CL/cl_platform.h my_types.h params.h compatibility.h

mfakto.o: mfakto.cpp $(AMD_APP_DIR)/include/CL/cl.h \
 $(AMD_APP_DIR)/include/CL/cl_platform.h params.h my_types.h compatibility.h \
 read_config.h parse.h sieve.h timer.h checkpoint.h filelocking.h \
 perftest.h mfakto.h output.h gpusieve.h signal_handler.h

perftest.o: perftest.cpp $(AMD_APP_DIR)/include/CL/cl.h \
 $(AMD_APP_DIR)/include/CL/cl_platform.h params.h my_types.h compatibility.h \
 read_config.h parse.h sieve.h timer.h checkpoint.h filelocking.h \
 signal_handler.h mfakto.h

menu.o: menu.h compatibility.h my_types.h

kbhit.o: kbhit.h
```

Comment: It works for me (up to date MSYS2, x86_64-w64-mingw32 toolchain, OCL from https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/OCL-SDK/releases/tag/1.0), at least up until the selftest. Try GDB to find out where it crashes? To build with debug symbols, replace compiler flags with `-Og -ggdb` or something similar.

Comment: I now think the issue is with my MinGW installation. After I installed the package from SourceForge rather than Win-builds, the program worked as expected.